# Failed opening required dompdf/autoload.inc.php

Tags: php, html, dreamweaver, wampserver, dompdf

I am developing a web system that can generate pdf file and I am using dompdf for the same.

I've tried many solutions that I found on the Internet but the result still the same. Can anyone out there help me, really need your help to solve this

```
    <?php

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';




//-------------------------------------post dari form Print.php-----------------------
$ID = $_POST['ID'];
$namaPenuhPemohon = $_POST['namaPenuh'];
$namaCina = $_POST['namaCina'];
$namaLain = $_POST['namaLain'];
$tempatLahir = $_POST['tempatLahir'];
$noICPemohon = $_POST['noIC'];
$tarikhDikeluarkan = $_POST['tarikhDikeluarkan'];

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//-----------------------------------Utk buat PDF file----------------------------------
$html =

  '<html><body>'.

  '<table border="0" width="95%">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" align="right"><img src="Logo/Jabatan-Imigresen.png" width="70" height="80"></td>
      <td align="center">BORANG INI DIKENAKAN BAYARAN SEBANYAK RM1.00</td>
      <td align="right">HAF 25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">SABAH, MALAYSIA <br> PERATURAN-PERATURAN IMIGRESEN TAHUN 1963 <i> <br>THE IMMIGRATION REGULATION, 1963 </i></td>
    </tr>
  </table>'.
  '<center>'.
  '<p><b>PERMOHONAN UNTUK MELANJUTKAN TEMPOH PAS</b>'.
  '<br>'.
  '<i> APPLICATION FOR EXTENSION OF PASS </i>'.
  '<br>'.
  '[Peraturan 8(2)]'.
  '</center>'.
  '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.
  '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.
  '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.
  '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.
  '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.
  '<i>[Regulation 8(2)]</i> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <font size="4"><b>H</b></font> No. '.$ID.
  '<br><br>'.

  '(Ingatan: Borang ini BUKAN untuk digunakan di mana sipemohon memohon untuk mendapatkan satu <br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; kebenaran masuk).'.
  '<br>'.
  '<i> (Note: This Form is NOT used where the applicant is applying for an Entry Permit). </i>'.
  '<br><br><br>'.
  '<center><b>MAKLUMAT PEMOHON</b></center><br>'.
  '<b>1. Nama Penuh &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; : </b> '.$namaPenuhPemohon.
  '<br><br>'.
  '<b>2. Nama Dalam Bahasa Cina &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; : </b> '.$namaCina.
  '<br><br>'.
  '<b>3. Nama Lain Yang Digunakan &nbsp; : </b> '.$namaLain.
  '<br><br>'.

  '</body></html>';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'potratit');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream('Borang Permohonan Melanjutkan Tempoh PAS.pdf');

?>
```

that is my code but the error really make me cant sleep for 2 days to solve it. so here i really hope someone can help me

really hope somebody can help me with this, I will be thankful of 
you

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @SmitRaval there is my code

Comment: Can you please show your directory structure?

Comment: I am sorry for late replay @Smit Raval , i put dompdf folder inside of IMG(my project name) file C:\wamp\www\IMG\dompdf

Comment: And where is your PHP file?

Comment: all my php file are inside the IMG folder

Comment: Can you please check if "dompdf/autoload.inc.php" file exist in your dompdf folder?

Comment: yes, it exist in the dompdf folder